# Runtime error with passing data between activities. Android

Tags: java, android

I really can't figure out what's the problem here, I did almost the same example i got from somewhere on net and it's working, but this one reports a runtime error when I click on the button to switch to secondActivity. But before I set up onActivityResult in first and sending result in second activity, it switched fine.

It's a little bit longer code, but it's nothing complicated. In first activity you click button to go to second activity, and there you pick two numbers, which are stored in object and sent by intent back to the first activity, and in first activity in textview you get the total of those numbers.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.parcelablevezba4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 42);


            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 42){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Object obj2 = data.getParcelableExtra("obje");
                int total = obj2.getFirstSummand() + obj2.getSecondSummand();
                tv1.setText(obj2.getFirstSummand()+"+"+obj2.getSecondSummand()+"is "+total);
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

SecondActivity

```
package com.example.parcelablevezba4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    Button btnOk;

    int firstSummand;
    int secondSummand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSecond);
        btnOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

        firstSummand = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
        secondSummand = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                Object obj = new Object();

                obj.setFirstSummand(firstSummand);
                obj.setSecondSummand(secondSummand);


                resultIntent.putExtra("obje", obj);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Object class

```
package com.example.parcelablevezba4;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Object implements Parcelable {
 private int firstSummand;
 private int secondSummand;

 public Object(){}

 public Object(Parcel p){
     this.firstSummand; = p.readInt();
     this.secondSummand; = p.readInt();
 }


 public int getFirstSummand(){
     return this.firstSummand;
 }

 public int getSecondSummand(){
     return this.secondSummand;;
 }

 public void setFirstSummand(int f){
     this.firstSummand = f;
 }

 public void setSecondSummand(int s){
     this.secondSummand; = s;
 }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel p, int flag) {

    p.writeInt(firstSummand);
    p.writeInt(secondSummand);

}

public static Parcelable.Creator<Object> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Object>() {

    @Override
    public Object createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Object(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Object[size];
    }
};

}
```

I translated this from my language, so if I mistyped somewhere sorry about that.

Error

```
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parcelablevezba4/com.example.parcelablevezba4.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.example.parcelablevezba4.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:30)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-17 13:20:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you post the actual runtime error ? It may be helpful.

Comment: @m4rtin Yes, I'll edit in sec.

Comment: @bliny : Please learn how to interpret logcat errors. It'll save you a lot of time and you can solve your own problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your `EditText`s are returning an empty string:

```
firstSummand = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
secondSummand = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
```

And then you try to parse that empty string.

Add a log before or even better a check:

```
String edit1 = et1.getText().toString();
String edit2 = et2.getText().toString();

Log.e("TAG", "First: "+edit1+" Second: "+edit2);

firstSummand = (edit1.isEmpty()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edit1);
secondSummand = (edit2.isEmpty()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edit2);
```